# Designing live video stream for wxWidgets

Tags: c++, client-server, video-streaming

In my application we will present the video stream from a traffic camera to a client viewer.  (And eventually several client viewers.)  The client should have the ability to watch the live video *or* rewind the video and watch earlier footage including video that occurred prior to connecting with the video stream.  We intend to use wxWidgets to view the video and within that we will probably use the wxMediaCtrl.

Now, from the above statements some of you might be thinking "Hey, he doesn't know what he's talking about."  And you would be correct!  I'm new to these concepts and I confused by the surplus of information.  **Are the statements above reasonable?  Can anyone recommend a basic server/client architecture for this?**  We will definitely be using C++ wxWidgets for the GUI, but perhaps wxMediaCtrl is not what I want... should I be directly using something like the ffmpeg libraries?

Our current method seems less than optimal.  The server extracts a bitmap from each video frame and then waits for the single client to send a "next frame" message, at which point the server sends the bitmap.  Effectively we've recreated our own awkward, non-standard, inefficient, and low-functionality video streaming protocol and viewer.  There has to be something better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out this C++ RTMP Server: http://www.rtmpd.com/. I quickly downloaded, compiled and successfully tested it without any real problems (on Ubuntu Maverick). The documentation is pretty good if a little all over the place. I suspect that once you have a streaming media server capable of supporting the typical protocols (which rtmpd seems to do), then writing a client should fall into place naturally, especially if you're using wxWidgets as the interface api. Of course, it's easy to write that here, from the comfort of my living room, it'll be a different story when you're knee deep in code :)

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your software such that:

The server connect, server grabs an image, passes it to ffmpeg establishing stream, then copy the encoded data from ffmpeg stream and send to client via network, if the connection drops, close the ffmpeg stream.

Maybe you can use the following to your own advantage:

http://www.kirsle.net/blog.html?u=kirsle&id=63

Answer (score 0):

There is a player called [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc). It has a library for c++ and you can use it to embed the player in your GUI application. It supports a very wide range of protocols. So you should leave connecting, retrieving and playing jobs to VLC and take care of the starting and stopping jobs only. It would be easy and probably a better solution than doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For media playing facility, both music and audio, you can a look on [GStream](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/).  And talking about the server, I think [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) (A network library in Python) should be good option.  The famous live video social website [justin.tv](http://justin.tv) is based on Twisted. Here you can read the story from [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/SuccessStories#Justin.tv).  Also, I built a group of server for streaming audio on Twisted, too. They can serve thousands of listener on line in same time.